# I am having a problem while packaging my electron app using the electron-builder?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

This error window appears as soon as I enter my app after packaging it using the electron-builder

[image]

although the devDependencies for electron-updater is included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`electron-builder` does not include devDependencies in the packaged application since they're exclusive for development, you should reinstall `electron-updater` as a dependency.

From the [`electron-builder`](https://www.electron.build/) website:

> A complete solution to package and build a ready for distribution Electron app for macOS, Windows and Linux with “auto update” support out of the box.
>
> - NPM packages management:
>
>   - Native application dependencies compilation (including Yarn support).
>   - **Development dependencies are never included**. You don’t need to ignore them explicitly.
>
> ...